# Visual Studio (List.Count - 1) = List.Count

Tags: vb.net, list, count

I've been trying around for a bit now and I'm totally confused why my program behaves this way.
I tried to search on google and here but maybe I just have trouble phrasing my question right or I'm the only one with this problem.

Anyways, so here's my problem:

```
Protected myList as List(Of CustomClass) = new List(Of CustomClass)

Public Sub mySub()
    Dim ListCount as Integer = myList.Count
    ListCount = ListCount - 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListCount Step 1
        If myList(i).MyStatus = FMyStatus Then
             myList(i).MyFunction.Invoke()
             myList.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This throws me an exception all the time that i is larger than the myList-index.
The problem is that ListCount even though I reduced it by 1 still stays the same, it's not possible to reduce it by 1.
But if I for example reduce it by 2, it's totally fine and does it stuff.

Is this common? Did I miss on something? I already tried to find something on the msdn website for the List.Count Property but wasn't able to find something that explains me why I can't reduce the value by 1.

Hope you guys can enlighten me.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop backwards to accomplish this:

```
For i As Integer = myList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
```

If you go the other way, when you remove an item, the list becomes smaller, but you are still trying to go to the end of the original list.